# How to insert data / update a column in table in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

I inserted records in a table using textbox and radiobuttonlist in my registration page. In registration page everything is all right and data is being submitted but as I go to part one question page and then click on next records aren't being updated. How can I update those column having null values using radiobutton  list?

Here is the image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXg42.jpg]

I want to update onlineshopping1, onlineshopping2, onlineshopping3, onlineshopping4, onlineshopping5 columns which fields are on other page.

Comment: "as I go to part one question page and then click on next records aren't being updated." this statement needs more clarity...Can you explain more about it ?

Comment: what does radiobuttonlisty have

Comment: part one i've  created another page which contains question list that data needs to be updated